# Webview reloading on Orientation Change in Honeycomb

Tags: android, android-webview, orientation-changes, android-orientation

I have a webview which is loading a url. If I change the orientation of my tablet the webview load's the URL again. How can I retain the state of webview on orientation change so that it does not restart loading the url. So far I've tried this :-

```
    @Override
   public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //Save the state of Webview
        wv.saveState(savedInstanceState);
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        // Restore the state of webview
       wv.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN );
    setContentView(R.layout.html);

    if(savedInstanceState!=null){
        // Restore webview state 
        wv.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
     }

    WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);

    wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        wv.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        wv.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
        wv.setInitialScale(50);
        wv.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        wv.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);

        _dialog = ProgressDialog.show(HtmlActivity.this, "", "Loading...", true, true);
        _dialog.setCancelable(true);
        _dialog.show();

        wv.loadUrl("http://www.samsung.com");

        wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
        {

                @Override
                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

                    return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(wv, url);
                }

                @Override
                public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                    //_dialog =ProgressDialog.show(HtmlActivity.this, "", "Please wait..."); 
                        super.onPageStarted(wv, url, favicon);
                }

                @Override
                public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                    try{
                         _dialog.dismiss();
                        }catch (Exception e) {
                            // TODO: handle exception
                        }
                      //  super.onPageFinished(wv, url);
                }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In your Manifest file, for the web-view's activity write:

```
 android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

for newer API's add the `screenSize`property too...

Comment: Hi Pallavi, I am using different layouts for both modes. Though this enabling android:configChanges="orientation" retains the webview state but actually messes up the layout.

Comment: You should use `RelativeLayout` in that case, so that it would adjust itself according to available space.

Comment: I am already using that....but the button sizes on the bottom of the screen below webview varies on both orientations. So if I start my activity on portrait mode and rotate it to landscape mode it shows me the buttons of the portrait mode and vice-versa.

Comment: That you need to handle in your XML.

Comment: This doesn't work properly on newer APIs , use this instead android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answer of @Pallavi, please read http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html to understand **why that reload happens**. The activity restart is an essential part of the activity lifecycle in Android.

Comment: @Bananewizen - I have gone through the documents already. I am able to restore images, strings, etc using onSaveInstanceState but I am not getting through to save webview's state.

Answer (score 1):

In your Manifest file, for the web-view's activity

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale"
```